# how to install all react-navigation package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, react-navigation

I'm a beginner in coding which means i follow tutorials from youtube. The project that i'm making is an Uber Clone. When I tried to install:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

it gives me error message saying:

Installing 4 SDK 45.0.0 compatible native modules and 1 other package using npm.

> npm install
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2
> npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
> npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.2.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements
> npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
> npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
> npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements
> npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
> resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-05T13_17_47_604Z-debug-0.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
(C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodeP    at actionAsync (C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\installAsync.ts:125:3)

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "uber-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank You

Comment: the error you are seeing is due to npm 7 peer dependencies. it looks like the issue is with npm 7, related to this issue: https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/pull/3545. you can uninstall react-native-elements or use yarn or npm 6 instead

Answer (score 0):

First remove `node_modules` folder then install again by running `npm install`. Then open your code in code editor and remove dependency `react-native-safe-area-context` by running `npm uninstall react-native-safe-area-context`

Comment: @dan-homola , I've tried what you said but there is an error when i do npm install again. here is what I get:

Comment: share snipshot of your error

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

Open your code in code editor and remore dependency react-native-safe-area-context by running `npm uninstall react-native-safe-area-context`

Run `npm update`

Comment: This does not solve OPs problem as mentioned in the comments of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it globally

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

it's work for me!

Comment: Your answer doesn't relate to the question asked regarding `react-navigation`

Comment: yes it's not related to only react navigation it's related to all lib